# Proper Syntax for a for-loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, syntax

Here's my code

```
days = 10
total = 0

for currentday in range(1, days +1):
 > bugs = int(input("how many bugs were collected on day"+ str(currentday),": ")
 > total += bugs
print("The total number of bugs caught by the end of all",days,"days was",total)
```

I keep experiencing syntax errors on line 6 or where the "total += bugs" is.
I can't even identify what the error is so I need help in finding what's wrong with it

Comment: Are the `>` part of your code? if so, there's your problem

Comment: The `>` in your code can't be helping.

Comment: You are not closing the input bracket in line 5, you are also using `,` instead of `+`. It should `bugs = int(input("how many bugs were collected on day"+ str(currentday) + ": "))`

Comment: The > were inserted to mark blocks on here and are not part of my actual code. I will omit them next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
days = 10
total = 0

for currentday in range(1, days +1):
    bugs = int(input(f"how many bugs were collected on day {currentday}: "))
    total += bugs
print("The total number of bugs caught by the end of all",days,"days was",total)
```

A: Your missing a bracket ")" on the end of line 6.

B: You cant put variables like that into an input, use the formatting option as seen above

Answer (score 0):

The '>'s aren't helping, but those were probably added when you copy-pasted your code. The main problem is simply a forgotten bracket on the line above. It ends `": ")` when it should end `": "))`

Furthermore, you can't just put commas to add strings and integers to make a string. You have to convert the integer variables `days` and `total` to strings first.

Here is your code with the errors resolved:

```
days = 10
total = 0

for currentday in range(1, days + 1):
    bugs = int(input("how many bugs were collected on day" + str(currentday) + ": "))
    total += bugs

print("The total number of bugs caught by the end of all ", str(days), " days was ", str(total))
```

Comment: The commas in the `print` call are fine. `print` takes multiple arguments and prints them all with a separator between them, with the separator defaulting to a single space. The comma in the `input` call is *not* fine.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thank you for the clarification! I will edit my answer right away. I was not aware print could be used like that.

Comment: I put the > to mark blocks as I think that's what the site told me to do to make it easier to read. I'll remove them next time. Also, I have used commas to insert integers into a string before.